# How can ı make capitalization checker with array some and map function?

Tags: javascript

I use OOP system. I have one product list add project and ı want to capitalization check. I know two solution for problem but doesn't work.
For example, I entered a product called "bag" and again I want the same product not to be capitalized. Different letters such as "bag" and "Bag" or "BAG" should not be written in capital letters. how can ı fix this? Thanks advance for answer. (You just need to answer one of the two solutions.) Full code: https://codepen.io/BerkayAkgurgen/pen/bGBNojw

```
// Some Solution
function addProductToUI(e) {
    const productName = nameInput.value.trim().toLowerCase();
    const productModel = modelInput.value.trim();
    const productPrice = priceInput.value.trim();
    let products = getTodosFromStorage();
    const urunlerim = new Urunler(productName, productModel, productPrice);
    if (productModel == "" || productName == "" || productPrice == "") {
        UI.showAlert("danger", "Hatalı Giriş")
    } else if (todos.some(a => a.trim().toLowerCase() == newTodoValuee)) {
        console.log("sdaas");
        return false;
    } else {
        let control = false;
        const products = Storage.getProductsFromStorage();
        products.forEach(function (product) {
            if (productName === product.productName) {
                control = true;
            }
        });

        if (control === false) {
            UI.urunEkle(urunlerim);
            Storage.addProductsToStorage(urunlerim);
            UI.showAlert("success", "Başarılı Giriş");
            nameInput.value = "";
            modelInput.value = "";
            priceInput.value = "";

        } else {
            UI.showAlert("danger", "Aynı Marka Girilemez");
        }
    }
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

```
// Map Solution
function addProductToUI(e) {
    const productName = nameInput.value.trim().toLowerCase();
    const productModel = modelInput.value.trim();
    const productPrice = priceInput.value.trim();
    let products = getTodosFromStorage();
    var words = todos.map(w => w.toLowerCase());
    const urunlerim = new Urunler(productName, productModel, productPrice);
    if (productModel == "" || productName == "" || productPrice == "") {
        UI.showAlert("danger", "Hatalı Giriş")
    } else if (words.includes(productName)) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("Aynı Todo");
        nameInput.value = "";
        return false;
    } else {
        let control = false;
        const products = Storage.getProductsFromStorage();
        products.forEach(function (product) {
            if (productName === product.productName) {
                control = true;
            }
        });

        if (control === false) {
            UI.urunEkle(urunlerim);
            Storage.addProductsToStorage(urunlerim);
            UI.showAlert("success", "Başarılı Giriş");
            nameInput.value = "";
            modelInput.value = "";
            priceInput.value = "";

        } else {
            UI.showAlert("danger", "Aynı Marka Girilemez");
        }
    }
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: can u provide us more information , what do you mean want to capitalization check , you want to check if product fields is capitalized ?

Comment: For example, I entered a product called "bag" and again I want the same product not to be capitalized. Different letters such as "bag" and "Çanta" or "BAG" should not be written in capital letters.

Comment: in the full code link u provided all work fine and in your code you have converte your product name to lowercase so it will never be saved as Capital letter ,so if we supposed you have entred "bag" then you will try to save "Bag" it will not added

Answer (score 0):

Ok, your code is huge, makes sense I guess, so I'll just give you a function you can use to only return common letters from a given `text` element(so that you can work with it)

The idea of how the function is used is that you store all values as lowercase **FROM THE INPUT** and do checks when **INPUT IS ALREADY LOWERED**

```js
var x=document.getElementById('x')
function lowerCaseInput(elem){return elem.value.toLowerCase()}
var obj={}


document.getElementById('b')
.addEventListener('click',function(ev){
  var input=lowerCaseInput(x)
  if(obj[input]){alert(`Error: "${input}" already exists`)}
  else{obj[input]=1; console.log(obj)}
})
```

```html
<input id="x" />
<button id="b">add value</button>
```